# Map Column names in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Input table

```
Header    DisplayName
Field1      EmpName
Field2      EmpID
Field3      IsActive
Filed4      Dept
```

And a Output table:

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Filed4
 A        1       +       Q
 B        2       +       R
```

How can I map the Display names from Input table onto the output table without explicitly specifying "Select Field1 AS 'EmpName', Field2 AS 'EmpID'" and so on?

Is there a fancy way of mapping the output table in a way that each field picks the Display Name from Input table?

***TIA***

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is your "input" table a meta table describing your "output" table? Are you trying to write dynamic sql based on the contents of your "input" table to select from your "output" table? I feel like you are making up terms and not defining them "input table" "output table" "map" "Display names". Can you rewrite to explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish. This feels kind of anti-patterny (database in a database anti-pattern)

Comment: Not sure where the values from the ouput table are coming from, but this is a pivot.

Comment: You can use dynamic sql, but generally that's not really something best handled in the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about your situation, but I would first try to handle with a view over your output table first. However, if that is now possible, you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '
    + STUFF((
        SELECT ', [' + Header + '] AS [' + DisplayName + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM tblInput FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    + ' FROM tblOutput'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql
```

It will support variables injected into SQL if you need as well.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT '
    + STUFF((
        SELECT ', [' + Header + '] AS [' + DisplayName + ']' AS [text()]
        FROM tblInput FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
    + ' FROM tblOutput O WHERE Field1 = @Field1'
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql, N'@Field1 VARCHAR(50)', @Field1 = 'A'
```